# BindingNavigator Copy to AddNewItem

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding, .net-4.5, bindingnavigator

When adding a new item via a `BindingNavigator`, how can I populate several fields of the new item with values from the previously selected item?

Note: On `BindingNavigatorAddNewItem.Click`, the `BindingNavigator` already has the new item loaded and the controls cleared to default values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [**`BindingNavigator`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.bindingnavigator.aspx) has to be bound to a data source. For it to share the same as a `DataGridView`, for instance, it needs to use a [**`BindingSource`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.bindingsource.aspx). So the added item is actually added to your underlying [**`BindingSource.DataSource`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.bindingsource.datasource.aspx).

There are two ways I can see to solve your issue.

Once both the [**`DataGridView`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.windows.forms.datagridview) and `BindingNavigator` are bound, even though you click on the [**`BindingNavigator.AddNewItem`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.bindingnavigator.addnewitem.aspx) button, a call to [**`BindingSource.AddNew()`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.bindingsource.addnew.aspx) method is made and the position of the [**`CurrencyManager`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.currencymanager%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) updates changes for your newly added item's position, so does the `BindingSource.Current` property by returning an instance of your newly added object, or else, the `BindingSource.CurrencyManager.Current` does the same.

> **1** - Use the [**`BindingSource.Current`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.bindingsource.current.aspx)

Type cast the `BindingSource.Current` object, assign your values, and you're done!

> **2** - Subscribe to the [**`BindingSource.AddingNew`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.bindingsource.addingnew.aspx) event

By doing so, you may access your instance through the  [**`BindingSource.AddignNewEventArgs`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.addingneweventargs.aspx), and use the [**`AddignNewEventArgs.NewObject`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.addingneweventargs.newobject.aspx) property to type cast it and assign your own default values to it.

Comment: The following results in `InvalidCastException`: `SomeDataSet.HelloWorldRow newRow (SomeDataSet.HelloWorldRow) HelloWorldBindingSource.Current;`

Comment: This seems to be the right answer (the `BindingSource.AddingNew` event).  However, I cannot seem to populate `AddingNewEventArgs.NewObject` with the correct type.  I created a separate question for that issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23378421/customize-stronglytyped-bindingsource-item-addition