# Customize StronglyTyped BindingSource Item Addition

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding, .net-4.5, bindingsource

I want to customize the addition of a new item into a `BindingSource` (all strongly-typed) as described on the following MSDN Article:

[How to: Customize Item Addition with the Windows Forms BindingSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a127sbc5%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

The code below results in `InvalidOperationException`: Objects added to a BindingSource's list must all be of the same type.  Also, the object `myTypesBindingSource.Current` seems to be a `DataRowView` with my relevant row inside.

How can I customize the addition of a strongly-typed `BindingSource`?

```
private void InitializeComponent()
{
    this.components = new System.ComponentModel.Container();

    this.someDataSet = new myDB.SomeDataSet();
    this.myTypesBindingSource = new System.Windows.Forms.BindingSource(this.components);
    this.myTypesTableAdapter = new myDB.SomeDataSetTableAdapters.myTypesTableAdapter();
    this.tableAdapterManager = new myDB.SomeDataSetTableAdapters.TableAdapterManager();
    this.myTypesBindingNavigator = new System.Windows.Forms.BindingNavigator(this.components);

    this.someIntValueTextBox = new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox();

    // someDataSet
    this.someDataSet.DataSetName = "SomeDataSet";
    this.someDataSet.SchemaSerializationMode = System.Data.SchemaSerializationMode.IncludeSchema;

    // myTypesBindingSource

    // As generated:
    // this.myTypesBindingSource.DataMember = "myTypes";
    // this.myTypesBindingSource.DataSource = this.someDataSet;
    this.myTypesBindingSource.DataSource = this.someDataSet;
    this.myTypesBindingSource.AddingNew += new System.ComponentModel.AddingNewEventHandler(this.myTypesBindingSource_AddingNew);

    // myTypesTableAdapter
    this.myTypesTableAdapter.ClearBeforeFill = true;

    // tableAdapterManager
    this.tableAdapterManager.BackupDataSetBeforeUpdate = false;
    this.tableAdapterManager.myTypesTableAdapter = this.myTypesTableAdapter;
    this.tableAdapterManager.UpdateOrder = myDB.SomeDataSetTableAdapters.TableAdapterManager.UpdateOrderOption.InsertUpdateDelete;

    // someIntValueTextBox
    this.someIntValueTextBox.DataBindings.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.Binding("Text", this.myTypesBindingSource, "someIntValue", true));
    this.someIntValueTextBox.Name = "someIntValueTextBox";
}

private void myTypesBindingSource_AddingNew(object sender, AddingNewEventArgs e)
{
    SomeDataSet.myTypesRow newRow = someDataSet.myTypes.NewmyTypesRow();
    newRow.someIntValue = 99;
    e.NewObject = newRow; 
}
```

Comment: +1 This made me investigate further details about DataSets and DataBinding that I had never went through yet. Thanks for allowing me to learn as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the example, it is not a strongly typed [**`BindingSource`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.bindingsource%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). As a matter of fact, the [**`AddingNewEventArgs.NewObject`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.addingneweventargs.newobject%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property is an object. So, assigning it any derived type shall make it.

Also, notice that the example uses a class object `DemoCustomer`, it is no `DataSet.Tables[0].Row` which returns a [**`DataRow`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarow.aspx). The game is a bit different, in my point of view, when using a [**`DataSet`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataset.aspx).

When one uses a `DataSet`, you'll have to set only a [**`DataTable`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.aspx) as the [**`BindingSource.DataSource`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.bindingsource.datasource%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), making you write something like:

```
BindingSource.DataSource = DataSet.Tables[0];
```

This way, when you add an item to the [**`BindingSource.List`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.bindingsource.list%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) using [**`BindingSource.AddNew()`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.bindingsource.addnew%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), the `BindingSource` "knows" that it has a `DataTable` as its `DataSource`, so it calls the [**`DataTable.NewRow()`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.newrow.aspx) method and a new `DataRow` is added to your `DataTable`! Thus, having a `DataRow` to handle instead of a simple object.

> Working with a **`DataRow`**

If you want to do similar to what the example on MSDN says, you'll have to create the row yourself.

```
DataRow newRow = DataSet.Tables[0].NewRow();
newRow.Columns["intColumn"] = 99;
e.NewObject = newRow;
```

This way, you shall be able to tell what default values you want.

Otherwise, if not, you might as well try this:

```
var newRow = (DataRow)e.NewObject;
newRow["intColumn"] = 99;
```

The weakness here is whenever you change the underlying database table column name, you'll have to come here, change the name of your `intColumn`, and recompile, and redeploy.

Besides, this shall not happen often, so it might be worthy depending on your environmental context.

> **EDIT #1**

After having paid more attention to:

> Also, the object myTypesBindingSource.Current seems to be a DataRowView with my relevant row inside

**From MSDN:** [`DataRowView`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarowview%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

> Whenever data is displayed, such as in a DataGrid control, only one version of each row can be displayed. The displayed row is a DataRowView.
>
> A DataRowView can have one of four different version states: Default, Original, Current, and Proposed.
>
> After invoking BeginEdit on a DataRow, any edited value becomes the Proposed value. Until either CancelEdit or EndEdit is invoked, the row has an Original and a Proposed version. If CancelEdit is invoked, the proposed version is discarded, and the value reverts to Original. If EndEdit is invoked, the DataRowView no longer has a Proposed version; instead, the proposed value becomes the current value. Default values are available only on rows that have columns with default values defined.

This means that when adding a new row, you're actually adding a `DataRowView`. You may access the current row by accessing its [**`DataRowView.Row`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarowview.row%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property.

Taking this into consideration, you might perhaps change the proposed solution in my initial answer to this:

```
var newRow = ((DataRowView)e.NewObject).Row;
newRow.Columns["intColumn"] = 99;
```

**EDIT:** (by Steven) Final Code

```
DataView dv = (DataView)myTypesBindingSource.List;
DataRowView drv = dv.AddNew();
SomeDataSet.myTypesRow newMyTypesRow = (SomeDataSet.myTypesRow)drv.Row;
newMyTypesRow.someIntValue = 53;
e.NewObject = drv;
myTypesBindingSource.MoveLast();
```

Comment: The Properties Editor only lets me set the BindingSource.DataSource to the DataSet.  There is no button to expand further.  If I change the value in the Designer.cs file, it reflects in the Properties window, but I still get the same error.

Comment: Doing it through the Form Designer may constraint some of the behaviour that is actually doable by code. I suggest you provide some further code sample that show how your `BindingSource`, `DataGridView`, `BindingNavigator` and the `DataSet` are initialized and later used. This might provide me with some more details in order to assist you further.

Comment: I dragged the myTypes DataTable from the Data Sources window onto the form which added all of the following: `someDataSet`, `myTypesBindingSource`, `myTypesTableAdapter`, `tableAdapterManager`, `myTypesBindingNavigator`.  I'll edit my original post to include more potentially relevant code.

Comment: How many tables do you have in `SomeDataSet`? A try to assign  `BindingSource.DataSource = someDataSet.Tables[0]` might help the cause. Have you tried, once everything is created in design mode, to initialize values programmatically?

Comment: Your code worked, but I wanted to assign values into a strongly-typed row.  I figured it out (see final code appended in your answer).

Comment: Your final suggestion didn't work as `e.NewObject` is `null`.

Comment: I'll remove it then, to avoid misconception for the other community users. If you'd like, please send me an email with a example application, and I shall take an eye out and see if I can improve something: will.marcouiller(at)groupe-wmi.com